# Universal app - Master Detail

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I am a bit confused about something I hope someone could clarify for me.
When I create a Universal Master Detail app, I notice that the tableview method didSelectRowAtIndexPath only deals with IPad selection.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
}
}
```

Can someone tell me where the iPhone tableview selection is being handled.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
```

is checking & adding the data only for Ipad, you need to check for iphone also or remove this check so that it can work for all devices

in case you want to check for IPhone then use one of these ways

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

or

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? If so, then the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is being handled via a segue with identifier @"showDetail".

So nothing is required in the table view delegate method.

If you turn off storyboards then you get this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (!self.detailViewController) {
            self.detailViewController = [[OCDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OCDDetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}
```

Which handles both iPhone and iPad cases.

Comment: Thanks for this useful feedback. Is there a way to add a seque for a Master Detail on iPad such that the selection will be handled on the iPad as it is on the iPhone?

Comment: By the way, this whole issue relates to a problem I am having that I describe in the following posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191554/ipad-vs-iphone-tableview-rows

Comment: There is no segue for iPad because there is no transition needed. The detail view as it is already visible. All that needs to happen is for the detail view's data to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. It turns out I had Core Data selected when I created the Universal App, however, I was not using Core Data properly. I have now leveraged Core Data and everything is working properly.